# How to execute a command via SSH in Elixir?

Tags: ssh, elixir

I know I can open a ssh connection to a remote server:

```
:ssh.start
:ssh.connect("11.22.33.44", 22, user: "my_login123")
```

But how can I actually send a command and receive a response from it? I don't mean the interactive mode, I want to just send a command and receive a reply.

Comment: it might be worth checking out https://github.com/rubencaro/sshex as it is written in elixir and from the readme, provides the features that you need.

Comment: @HarrisonLucas, it uses :ssh, what's the difference?

Comment: You have the tag [tag:elixir], you does not have the tag [tag:erlang] and you ask pure erlang question, rejecting perfectly valid correct elixir-specific answer by @harrison-lucas. This is a mess.

Comment: @mudasobwa, ты чего на людей сегодня кидаешься? то на робина наехал, теперь на меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might just be easier to use an Elixir library such as SSHex as this actually uses the erlang :ssh library but provides a much nicer interface as well as making it simpler to accomplish what you are after.

E.g. From the readme

```
{:ok, conn} = SSHEx.connect ip: '123.123.123.123', user: 'myuser'

SSHEx.cmd! conn, 'mkdir -p /path/to/newdir'
res = SSHEx.cmd! conn, 'ls /some/path'
```

Where the value of `res` will be the response from the command

**EDIT**
However, if you are set on using :ssh. Then you would need to use the `:ssh_connection` modules `exec` command which takes in the `:ssh` connection as a parameter.

See this [link here](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssh/using_ssh.html#id60929) for more detail on how to do this.

Comment: how can I do that in pure ":ssh"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that uses only `:ssh` and no external libraries. To run it you will need to have [public key login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) set up on your target host. For more information, read the Erlang [SSH User's Guide](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-1/apps/ssh/users_guide.html).

## ssh-connect.exs

```
#! /usr/bin/env elixir
:ssh.start()
{:ok, conn} = :ssh.connect('raspi', 22,
  silently_accept_hosts: true,
  user: System.get_env("USER") |> to_charlist(),
  user_dir: Path.join(System.user_home!(), ".ssh") |> to_charlist(),
  user_interaction: false,
)
{:ok, chan} = :ssh_connection.session_channel(conn, :infinity)
:success = :ssh_connection.exec(conn, chan, 'uname -a', :infinity)
for _ <- 0..3 do
  receive do
    {:ssh_cm, ^conn, value} -> IO.inspect(value)
  end  
end
:ok = :ssh.close(conn)
```

## Sample output

```
{:data, 0, 0, "Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50+ #970 Mon Feb 20 19:12:50 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux\n"}
{:eof, 0}
{:exit_status, 0, 0}
{:closed, 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SSHex [library](https://github.com/rubencaro/sshex) can very convenient to build SSH connection.

Here is example below:

```
defmodule SshDemo do
  @moduledoc false

  def connect do
    {:ok, conn} = SSHEx.connect ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user: 'root', password: 'xxxxx'
    SSHEx.cmd! conn, 'mkdir -p newdir'
  end
end
```

If you use mix to create your project. You just add dependency in **mix.exs** file and run-- "**mix deps.get**"

```
defp deps do
  [{:sshex, "2.1.2"}]
end
```

Then, you may compile this module. use -- **"mix deps.compile"**.
Run above example will make a folder named **newdir** in ~/ path

[image]